# Subselect em banco Oracle

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Estou tentando elaborar uma consulta e dentro de um dos meus joins é necessário ser feito um subselect para garantir a integridade da consulta como o exemplo abaixo:

```
select t01.teste           
from teste t01                
left join tes_teste_2 t02                   
on t01.isn_teste = t02.isn_teste           
and t02.isn_pessoa = (select min(t04.isn_pessoa) from tes_teste t04 
where t04.isn_teste = t01.isn_teste)
where t01.isn_empresa = 666
```

O problema que me retorna que "**ORA-01799: uma coluna não pode ser externamente unida a uma subconsulta**"

Gostaria de uma ajuda como poderia elaborar esse subselect como condição. Salientando que utilizamos o Oracle 11G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma alternativa seria

```
select t01.teste           
from teste t01
inner join 
(
   select isn_teste, min(isn_pessoa) isn_pessoa
   from   tes_teste 
   group by isn_teste
) t04         
  on t04.isn_teste = t01.isn_teste      
left join tes_teste_2 t02                   
  on t01.isn_teste = t02.isn_teste           
 and t02.isn_pessoa = t04.isn_pessoa
where t01.isn_empresa = 666
```

Outra alternativa seria passar a condição para a cláusula `where`

```
select t01.teste           
from teste t01                
inner join tes_teste_2 t02                   
on t01.isn_teste = t02.isn_teste           
where t01.isn_empresa = 666
  and t02.isn_pessoa = (
         select min(t04.isn_pessoa) 
           from tes_teste t04 
          where t04.isn_teste = t01.isn_teste)
```

Comment: Obrigado, consegui resolver o meu problema

Answer (score 0):

Uma subconsulta pode retornar mais de um registro, por lógica não se deve usar o operador `=` e sim o `in`.

Uma maneira diferente para fazer está consulta é:

```
select a.teste
  from teste a,
       tes_teste_2 b
 where a.isn_teste = b.isn_teste
   and b.isn_pessoa in ( select min(c.isn_pessoa)
                           from tes_teste c
                          where c.isn_teste = a.isn_teste )
   and a.isn_empresa = 666;
```

Comment: O @user2992172 indicou claramente que é necessário um subselect para garantir a integridade do resultado. Isto indica que a table tes_teste_2 tem vários registos para cada isn_teste. Logo esta query não irá produzir o resultado esperado. Deixo apenas um comentário em relação à sintaxe: Desde a introdução do ANSI-92 que a junção implicita de duas tabelas deveria ser considerada obsoleta, sendo que, por exemplo o SQL Server, já não suporta algumas das anteriores opções (*= e =*, por exemplo)

Comment: @bruno falta de atenção a minha em não respeitar a exigência do AP, irei corrigir, obrigado.

Comment: Obrigado, consegui resolver o meu problema